# How to apply a function to every possible pairwise combination of files stored in a common directory

Tags: r, function, csv, for-loop

I have a directory containing a large number of csv files. I would like to load the data into R and apply a function to every possible pair combination of csv files in the directory, then write the output to file.

The function that I would like to apply is `matchpt()` from the `biobase` library which compares locations between two data frames.

Here is an example of what I would like to do (although I have many more files than this):

1. Three files in directory: A, B and C
2. Perform matchpt on each pairwise combination: 
   `nn1 = matchpt(A,B)` 
   `nn2 = matchpt(A,C)`
   `nn3 = matchpt(B,C)`
3. Write nn1, nn2 and nn3 to csv file.

I have not been able to find any solutions for this yet and would appreciate any suggestions. I am really not sure where to go from here but I am assuming that some sort of nested for loop is required to somehow cycle sequentially through all pairwise combinations of files. Below is a beginning at something but this only compares the first file with all the others in the directory so does not work!

```
library("Biobase")

# create two lists of identical filenames stored in the directory:
filenames1 = list.files(path=dir, pattern="csv$", full.names=FALSE, recursive=FALSE)
filenames2 = list.files(path=dir, pattern="csv$", full.names=FALSE, recursive=FALSE)

for(i in 1:length(filenames2)){
# load the first data frame in list 1
  df1 <- lapply(filenames1[1], read.csv, header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  df1 <- data.frame(df1)
# load a second data frame from list 2
  df2 <- lapply(filenames2[i], read.csv, header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  df2 <- data.frame(df2)

# isolate the relevant columns from within the two data frames
dat1 <- as.matrix(df1[, c("lat", "long")]) 
dat2 <- as.matrix(df2[, c("lat", "long")])

# run the matchpt function on the two data frames
nn <- matchpt(dat1, dat2)

#Extract the unique id code in the two filenames (for naming the output file)
file1 = filenames1[1]
code1 = strsplit(file1,"_")[[1]][1]
file2 = filenames2[i]
code2 = strsplit(file2,"_")[[1]][1]
outname = paste(code1, code2, sep=”_”)
outfile = paste(code, "_nn.csv", sep="")
write.csv(nn, file=outname, row.names=FALSE)

}
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks!

Comment: Try `combn(c(1,2,3),m=2)`

Comment: `outer()` may be helpful, but this counts pairs twice, both (a,b) and (b,a), so you could combine it with `upper.tri()`.

Comment: Your code only compares the first file to the others because you only have one loop and df1 is always based on filenames1[1]. You only need 1 set of filenames. Then use two loops (looping from i:length(filenames) and from (i+1):length(filenames). This will give you all pairwise comparisons.

Comment: @ Eddie: Could you give me an example of how to implement this? I am not an advanced R user so am struggling to know how the two for loops would relate to one another. Many thanks!

Comment: @ zx8754 / Stephan: Thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this example:

```
#dummy filenames
filenames <- paste0("file_",1:5,".txt")

#loop through unique combination
for(i in 1:(length(filenames)-1))
for(j in (i+1):length(filenames))
  {
  flush.console()
  print(paste("i=",i,"j=",j,"|","file1=",filenames[i],"file2=",filenames[j]))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like:

```
out <- combn( list.files(), 2, FUN=matchpt )
write.table( do.call( rbind, out ), file='output.csv', sep=',' )
```

This assumes that `matchpt` is expecting 2 strings with the names of the files and that the result is the same structure each time so that the `rbind`ing makes sense.

You could also write your own function to pass to `combn` that takes the 2 file names, runs `matchpt` and then appends the results to the csv file.  Remember that if you pass an open filehandle to `write.table` then it will append to the file instead of overwriting what is there.

Comment: @ Greg: thanks for the answer, apologies for my delayed response. Unfortunately this doesn't work. I think it is because matchpt works with matrices not filename strings. I get the following error message: Error in combn(list.files(fns), 2, FUN = matchpt) : n < m. Any ideas?

Comment: @Emily, write your own function that takes the 2 filenames, loads the needed data, does any editing to get things ready for `matchpt`, then passes the proper matrices to `matchpt`.  Then pass your new function to `combn`.  Or use `lapply` to load in all the files to memory (if they fit reasonably) convert to the appropriate matrices and store them in a list.  The pass that list to `combn` in place of `list.files()`.

Comment: @ Greg. Thanks, sorry I am struggling with this. How does one "convert a list of data.frames into a list of matrices that combn accepts? When I try `matlist <- as.matrix(lapply(filelist,read.csv, …))` and pass this to `combn()` it still doesn't work. I get the following error: `Error in storage.mode(x) = "double" : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'`. Please could you give me a working example of how to get from a list of filenames to combn? I am not an advanced R user. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @Emily, there are a couple of options, but a simple one would by something like:  `dflist <- lapply(filelist,read.csv)` followed by `matlist <- lapply(dflist, as.matrix)`.  Another option would be `matlist <- lapply(filelist, function(x) as.matrix(read.csv(x)))`.

Comment: @ Thanks for this, but this list of matrices still doesn't work in combn() with matchpt. I wonder if combn() works on matrices? The description suggests it requires vectors as inputs. Matchpt requires a two column matrix.

Comment: @Emily, try `combn(seq_along(matlist), FUN=function(x,y) matchpt(matlist[[x]],matlist[[y]]))`.

Answer (score 1):

In response to my question I seem to have found a solution. The below uses a for loop to perform every pairwise combination of files in a common directory (this seems to work and gives EVERY combination of files i.e. A & B and B & A):

```
# create a list of filenames
filenames = list.files(path=dir, pattern="csv$", full.names=FALSE, recursive=FALSE)

# For loop to compare the files
for(i in 1:length(filenames)){

  # load the first data frame in the list
  df1 = lapply(filenames[i], read.csv, header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  df1 = data.frame(df1)
  file1 = filenames[i]
  code1 = strsplit(file1,"_")[[1]][1] # extract unique id code of file (in case where the id comes before an underscore)
  # isolate the columns of interest within the first data frame
  d1 <- as.matrix(df1[, c("lat_UTM", "long_UTM")]) 

  # load the comparison file
  for (j in 1:length(filenames)){

    # load the second data frame in the list
    df2 = lapply(filenames[j], read.csv, header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    df2 = data.frame(df2)
    file2 = filenames[j]
    code2 = strsplit(file2,"_")[[1]][1] # extract uniqe id code of file 2 
    # isolate the columns of interest within the second data frame
    d2 <- as.matrix(df2[, c("lat_UTM", "long_UTM")])

  # run the comparison function on the two data frames (in this case matchpt)
    out <- matchpt(d1, d2)
  # Merge the unique id code in the two filenames (for naming the output file)
    outname = paste(code1, code2, sep="_")
    outfile = paste(outname, "_out.csv", sep="")
  # write the result to file
    write.csv(out, file=outfile, row.names=FALSE) 
   }
}
```

Comment: Would result of `A & B` be different from `B & A`, if not why recalculate?

Comment: @ zx8754: I would like not to recalculate (i.e. only calculate A&B) but I haven't found a working way to do this yet. Suggestions would be much appreciated. I have tried `for (j in i+1:length(filenames))` but this doesn't quite work. I seem to be missing another statement somewhere.